# HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4]) - BUT NOT Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

```
TIC Read Status [2:0x6040001660c0]: 1:57
<10> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
<10> finished with error - code: -1005
```

I can't figure out this error. There are several threads about this, but they are all about uploading with alamofire. I have alamofire in my app, but not in this view controller and I don't use alamofire for this connection.

The error appears in about 1 out of 20 connection.

Here is my code

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses() if let requestURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/test.php") {
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "task_id=1"
urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

                // Async Stuff
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                })
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            self.errorAction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1005 means `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`, which rarely happens in usual network environments. Is your testing server properly configured? Or aren't you requesting a huge resource? By the way, you can omit `as URLRequest`.